# Forcing user to select a row in tableview before navigating

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to ensure user selects a row from a list of rows (row of schedules) displayed in a tableview controller before navigating to another controller. So in the didSelectRow method, I set a boolean variable scheduleSelected to true. In my viewWillDisappear, I check on scheduleSelected and it it is false then I raise an alert and reload the tableview so I stay on the same tableview instead of navigating. It is not working it navigates to another controller anyways but does raise an alert which is too late.

How can I force the user to select a row before navigating out of the current tableview controller?

May be there is easier way instead of this cumbersome procedure. Please let me know.

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if (scheduleSelected == false ) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "UIAlertController", message: "Select Row", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.message = "Choose a Schedule"
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }else {
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Profiles" )
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.navigationController
         let tabController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as! ViewTabBarController
        let navController = tabController.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController
        navController.popToViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: use `self.myTableView.selectRow(at: <#T##IndexPath?#>, animated: <#T##Bool#>, scrollPosition: <#T##UITableViewScrollPosition#>)`

Comment: Why you don´t make all your navigation process in `didSelectRow`?

Comment: None of the suggested methods work because I have an underlying issue. I want the controllers to move in this sequence A->B->C->B->A. In A prepareSegue I load B via PushController. So when I move forward from A it slides across B and stops at C and when I back from C it goes to B and when I back from B back it goes to A. The whole thing works nicely. Because of this my ViewDidAppear in C does not get triggered. But if I use your method of putting the logic in didSelectRow of C and the user never selects the row it just navigates anyway. So I don't know how to embed the logic and where?

Comment: I am sorry there is typo - I meant viewWillDisappear function will not get triggered in controller C. I need to push the logic inside Controller C into a function which will have to be executed as soon as I navigate on the back button of Controller C. There is also a forward bar button item on controller C and I don't want any action to be triggered when I nvigae from C forward to some other controller D

Comment: I did clean and rebuild and when I hit the back button the ViewWillDisappear gets executed, I can step through the code, but (1) AlertController does get displayed and (2) self.tableView.reloadData() does not retain the current view controller instead it moves to the other controller

Answer (score 0):

How you are navigating out of the current tableview controller using button action or using segue.

If you are using segue, then you have to handle this code like below:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (scheduleSelected == false ) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "UIAlertController", message: "Select Row", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.message = "Choose a Schedule"
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: This never gets executed for reasons I mentioned in response to  Reinier Melian